# Why is my data printing to the last index of my worksheet names array?

Tags: excel, vba

I am compiling worksheet names into an array so I can cycle through files in a folder and print them in a concurrent fashion. Here is the code used to create that array:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Update_Data_And_OPR()
    Dim wbTemplate As Workbook: Set wbTemplate = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsInputs As Worksheet: Set wsInputs = wbTemplate.Worksheets("Inputs")
    Dim strDate As String: strDate = "02/25/2020" 'InputBox("Please Enter Date of Data (mm/dd/yyyy) : ", Default:=Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy"))
    Dim strFolderName As String: strFolderName = "02.25.20" 'InputBox("Please Enter Data Folder Date (mm.dd.yy) Include 0's: ", Default:=Format(Now, "mm.dd.yy"))

    With wbTemplate
        Dim varWsName, i
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        ReDim varWsName(3 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                Select Case ws.Name
                    Case "Inputs", "Data --->>>"
                    Case Else
                        i = i + 1
                        varWsName(i) = ws.Name
                End Select
            Next
            wsInputs.Range("B1").Value = strDate
            wsInputs.Range("B2").Value = strFolderName
    End With
```

When I want to start printing to my `wbTemplate`,  `i` is referenced as the last worksheet in the array, and I want it to cycle back and start printing from the first index value (first worksheet in `wbTemplate`). How can I get it cycle back through?

```
Dim BasePath As String: BasePath = "\\com\data\" & strFolderName & "\"
Dim filename As String: filename = Dir(BasePath & "\*.xlsx")
Dim wb As Workbook

    Do While filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(BasePath & "\" & filename)
        With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            For i = LBound(varWsName) To UBound(varWsName)
                .UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy Destination:=wbTemplate.Worksheets(varWsName(i)).UsedRange.Offset(1)
            Next i
        End With
        wb.Close
    filename = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

For instance, `Corp` is the first index of `varWsname`, but when it starts to print the first file in `BasePath`, it prints it to `Corp32`, which is the last index of `varWsName`.

Comment: Why are you using `i` again in `Destination:=wbTemplate.Worksheets(varWsName(i)).UsedRange.Offset(1)`?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to loop through an array.

Comment: @BigBen, what else would I use to reference the the indices? Since I'm storing each ws name value in `varWsName` with `i`, wouldn't I also be designating where the data prints by adding in `Worksheets(varWsName(i))`?

Comment: You need to loop through the array: `For i = LBound(varWsName) to Ubound(varWsName)`.

Comment: @BigBen and where would that go within the `Do While` loop? Do I need to place that after the with statement?

Comment: Yes and make sure to include a `Next` to close the loop

Comment: @BigBen Hey, so I sort of got it, but it's just iterating the same data print to each worksheet. How can I place the `for i` loop to make sure after it prints a set of data, it closed out and opens the next file and then references the next `varWsName` index

Comment: Ah... that's what you want to do. Well then you might have a problem. I doubt `Dir` is going to open the files in the order you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array's index  start from 3. So i shoud start with 3.
And you defined  ReDim varWsName(3 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count) , so above code should modify. i must start with 3.

```
Dim BasePath As String: BasePath = "\\com\data\" & strFolderName & "\"
Dim filename As String: filename = Dir(BasePath & "\*.xlsx")
Dim wb As Workbook
    i = 2
    Do While filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(BasePath & "\" & filename)
        i = i + 1
        With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

                .UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy Destination:=wbTemplate.Worksheets(varWsName(i)).UsedRange.Offset(1)

        End With
        wb.Close
    filename = Dir
    Loop
```

Comment: It should be `i=i+1` and not `i=1+1`.